# Adding Search form in existing code

Tags: html, css

I have a Megamenu on my website and it works in all browsers apart from Google Chrome.  It just doesn't appear.

Please take a look at the header on the homepage on Firefox and then take a look at it in Google Chrome.

The [website](http://modatone.com)

You'll see in Chrome, the Menu isn't there but in Firefox it is.

Can you see why this is happening?

Cheers

Comment: Don't bother trying to debug broken code: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmodatone.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 (205 Errors, 223 warning(s))... see also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Also, linking to a commercial site makes your post seem (indirectly) spammy to me, even though you disclosed it was your site.

Comment: Where are you trying to add a search form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `position:fixed` to `position:relative` on `<div id="megamenu"></div>` and it shows up.

Looks like your CSS for elements around it is throwing it all off though, so this little fix might not get everything looking the same in both browsers.